# How to config two different applications in different EC2 instances under the same domain in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm setting up new two servers in different EC2 instances, and want to run two different applications, one on each EC2 instance:

`3.14.23.108:8080/clients 
18.23.34.23:8080/products`

I need that those endpoints run under the same domain Route53:

`www.mydomain.com`

And I expect some like this:

`www.mydomian.com/clients
www.mydomian.com/products`

I know some services of AWS like ELB, Api Gateway, and CloudFront but don't find a good example or tutorial por that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API Gateway with proxies to specific EC2 instances. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/ in the bottom search for "Use HTTP Proxy integration" and specify HTTP. Then set Route53 alias to the API Gateway.

Comment: Because is most cost-efficient than ELB, Api Gatway is the best way to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup AWS application load balancer with path base routing .

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

[image]